# JS Accordion - replacing a traditional for loop with forEach

Tags: javascript

So as I've slowly been learning JS I've been going through my site to improve any previous code.

One thing I've been doing lately is replacing for loops with forEach and so far all good apart from one which I can't figure out. It's for an accordion which closes one as another opens, but also scrolls the current one into view (it's for a mobile footer menu).

The top first for loop I can solve no problem, but it's the second one in that I'm struggling with and not even sure if it even can be done with forEach:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName('footer-accordion');
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) { // I can replace this one with forEach no problem
    acc[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.classList.toggle('active');
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === 'block') {
            panel.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            panel.style.display = 'block';
            for (let j = 0; j < acc.length; j++) { // This is the one I am struggling on!!
                if (this.classList != acc[j].classList) {
                    acc[j].classList.remove('active');
                    acc[j].nextElementSibling.style.display = 'none';
                    panel.scrollIntoView({
                        block: 'end',
                        behavior: 'smooth'
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this not working for you? can you share your html to help with testing?

```js
acc.forEach((current)=>{ 
                if (this.classList != current.classList) {
                    current.classList.remove('active');
                    current.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'none';
                    panel.scrollIntoView({
                        block: 'end',
                        behavior: 'smooth'
                    });
                }
            })
```

Comment: Since `acc` is a HTML Collection, it can not be iterated directly with .forEach() (but I don't think that's the problem, since that's already relevant in the outer loop...)

Comment: Can you share your html?

Comment: me? `[...acc].forEach()` or `Array.from(acc).forEach()`

Comment: oh my bad aha, thought you were OP lmao wasn't paying attention

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Daniel your code is what I first tried, but it stops the behaviour of one accordion closing as another opens and also it scrolling into view. As Corrl stated and what I was beginning to suspect, I don't think this can achieved any other way - including forEach. I have created a fiddle here though: https://jsfiddle.net/Luoz6079/

Comment: Just tried again, but this time used Corrl's 'Arry.from(acc)' and working now: https://jsfiddle.net/uftgm9zj Thanks so much!!:) One strange thing though is that on line 11, if you replace the function shorthand: Array.from(acc).forEach((current) => { with a tradition function: Array.from(acc).forEach(function(current) { it all stops working?